# Secure Web services with Oauth in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, security, oauth

I want to implement Oauth to protect my PHP Web Services,i have been following [this link](http://oauth.net/code/) but found that some of them link are not working.And the working example had implemented in slim,flight some different frameworks in php and  i'm newbie in it.My problem is i want to implement Oauth in Codeignter framework to protect Web Service and as per oauth site i've got a link by Alex Bilbie which is deprecated and not working. So if someone had done this before in codeigniter please let me know , Simple PHP would be also fine, later on i can modify it to fit in codeigniter.

Comment: That you want? https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2

Comment: I had it already but i wanted to make it for my own provider.Provider will be site itself and when user comes i want to authorize them with same method which oauth uses.

Answer (score 3):

I find Brent Shaffer's [OAuth2 Server Library for PHP](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/) an excellent library!

In the [cookbook](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/) you can find many examples on how to integrate it into certain frameworks, unfortunately CodeIgniter isn't one of them. But the documentation is very good, and you can use the cookbooks on the other frameworks as a guide for doing it in CodeIgniter.

You can find the library [on Github](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php).

Comment: And I guess you choose not to use it. Maybe you can sum up which libraries you tried, and what you found lacking?

Comment: Actually i had tried www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-php-oauth-server/ which is quite simple and easy to implement.But if anything would be implemented on codeigniter will be helpful.